# Detail Band border in FastReport VCL 5

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Is there a way in FastReport VCL 5 to put a frame around the outside of a detail band?   I am trying to achieve the following:

[image: Sample Report]

Note the Groups and User Privileges boxes. Both of these boxes are multi-columned details of the master detail. Note how the box frames the outside of the band. I am trying to do this in Fast Report 5 but can't seem to get it to work. My current idea has the main page with 2 sub-reports (1 for the groups and 1 for the privs). But, I cannot figure out how to get a frame to appear around just the outside. Here is my main page setup:

[image: Main Report Layout]

Here is the layout of the sub-report:

[image: Sub-report Layout]

I need to know that I can do this in Fast Report because our old reporting system uses it everywhere! Thanks!

Comment: check for fast report user manual, there's a section to display data in form of a table. oddly I can't put the link here

Comment: @saintfalcon: yes, I saw the example they had.  The problem is that I have multiple columns and I only want a border around the outside with no lines in between the columns and rows.  I put this same question on the Fast Report forums and I seem to have stumped them.

Comment: Have you tried doing it a bit dodgily but adding a header that has say a Text Object with a boarder on the bottom and the same with footer but boarder on the top. Then just add boarders on the left and right on the detail band.

Answer (score 0):

Use overlay band and draw a rectangle. In event onBeforePrint, insert code:

```
procedure Page1OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  shape1.Height:= 1050;
end;
```